# Rewriting linked list function without a NULL variable

Tags: php, linked-list

This is how my `LinkedList` class looks like in PHP. I am trying to figure out if I can rewrite my `reverse_list_recursively()` function more elegantly without having the funky `$current = NULL`. The reason I have it is because I need to pass `$current` in my recursion call. I'm not sure if there is another way to do it.

```
<?php

class ListNode {
    public $data;
    public $next;

    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->next = NULL;
    }

    function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class LinkList {

    // points to the first node
    private $head;

    // node count
    private $count;

    function __construct() {
        $this->head = NULL;
        $this->count = 0;
    }

    // checks if the list is empty or not
    function is_empty() {
        return ($this->head == NULL);
    }

    // inserts data at the beginning of the list
    public function insert_beg($data) {

        $link = new ListNode($data);
        $link->next = $this->head;
        $this->head = &$link;
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function insert_last($data) {
        $current = $this->head;

        if($current == NULL) {
           $this->insert_beg($data);

        } else {

            while($current->next != NULL) {
                $current = $current->next;
            }
            $link = new ListNode($data);
            $current->next = &$link;
            $link->next = NULL;
            $this->count++;
        }
    }

    public function delete_first_node() {
        if($this->head != NULL) {
            if($this->head->next != NULL) {
                $this->head = $this->head->next;
                $this->count--;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete_last_node() {

        $current = $this->head;
        if($current != NULL) {

            $prev = $current;
            while($current->next != NULL) {
                $prev = $current;
                $current = $current->next;
            }
            $current = $prev;
            $current->next = NULL;
            $this->count--;
        }
    }

    public function delete_node($data) {
        $current = $prev = $this->head;
        if ($current == NULL) {
            return;
        } else {
            while($current->data != $data && $current->next != NULL) {
                $prev = $current;
                $current = $current->next;
            }
            if($current->data == $data) {
                $prev->next = $current->next;
                $this->count--;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    public function reverse_list_iteratively() {
        $current = $this->head;

        // if the list is empty or only one element in the list return
        if($current == NULL || $current->next == NULL) {
            return;
        } else {
            $next = $prev = NULL;
            while($current != NULL) {
                $next = $current->next;
                $current->next = $prev;
                $prev = $current;
                $current = $next;

            }
            $this->head = $prev;
        }
    }

    public function reverse_list_recursively($current = NULL) {
        $current = $this->head;

        // base case when the current is empty
        if($current->next == NULL) {
            $this->head = $current;
            return $current;
        } else {
            $this->reverse_list_recursively($current->next);
            $current->next->next = $current;
            $current->next = NULL;
        }

    }

    public function print_list() {
        $current = $this->head;
        echo "\nThe list is: ";
        while($current != NULL) {
            echo "$current->data" . " ";
            $current = $current->next;
        }
    }

    public function get_size() {
        return $this->count;
    }

}
    $totalNodes = 10;

    $list = new LinkList();


    echo "Is list empty before adding nodes: ";
    var_export( $list->is_empty());
    echo "\n";

    for($i=1; $i <= $totalNodes; $i++) {
        $list->insert_last($i);
    }

    echo "Is list empty after adding nodes: "; 
    var_export( $list->is_empty());
    echo "\n";

    echo "Size of the list: " .  $list->get_size();
    echo "\n";

    echo "List is: ";
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";


    echo "Deleting first node: ";
    $list->delete_first_node();
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";

    echo "Deleting last node: ";
    $list->delete_last_node();
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";

    echo "Deleting node 6: ";
    $list->delete_node(6);
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";

    echo "Reversing the list iteratively";
    $list->reverse_list_iteratively();
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";

    echo "Reversing the list rec";
    $list->reverse_list_iteratively();
    $list->print_list();
    echo "\n";



?>
```

Results:

> ```
> Is list empty before adding nodes: true
> Is list empty after adding nodes: false
> Size of the list: 10
> List is: 
> The list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
> Deleting first node: 
> The list is: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
> Deleting last node: 
> The list is: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
> Deleting node 6: 
> The list is: 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 
> Reversing the list iteratively
> The list is: 9 8 7 5 4 3 2 
> Reversing the list rec
> The list is: 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at your code. First notice that you do not actually test your `reverse_list_recursively` method. This can be seen by looking at

```
  echo "Reversing the list rec";
  $list->reverse_list_iteratively();
  $list->print_list();
  echo "\n";
```

You are actually just calling `reverse_list_iteratively` again.

In fact, your recursive implementation doesn't work at all. Let's take a look at it.

```
public function reverse_list_recursively($current = NULL) {
    $current = $this->head;

    // base case when the current is empty
    if($current->next == NULL) {
        $this->head = $current;
        return $current;
    } else {
        reverse_list_recursively($current->next);
        $current->next->next = $current;
        $current->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

Notice that you pass in the parameter `$current`, but then the first thing you do is assign to `$current`, so that the argument the function is called with has no effect. Any time this function is called, `$current` will wind up having the value `$this->head`. Then assume this `LinkList` is not empty, the first if will never evaluate to true, so that the function evaluation will always precede to the recursive function call. Thus we get into a infinite recursion which will lead to a stack overflow. We have come full circle.

Also, since your recursive function call is actually calling a method and not a function, the line

```
    reverse_list_recursively($current->next);
```

should really be

```
    $this->reverse_list_recursively($current->next);
```

There are a few other problems. For one thing, when the `if` branch is taken, you `return` a value. This doesn't make sense because reversing a list shouldn't return a value, and you don't return a value when the `if` branch isn't taken.

Another problem is that you always set `$current->next = NULL`, but if in your recursion, you are somewhere in the middle of the list, then you do not want `$current->next==NULL`, instead you want `$current->next` to be the node that had originally been before `$current`.

Now I wrote an implementation. Let's look at it.

```
    private function reverse_list_right_of_node($node) {
        //We have reached the end.
        //This is where our head goes.
        if($node->next==NULL){ 
            $this->head = $node;
            return;
        }
        $nextNode = $node->next;
        //recursively reverse the rest of the list after the next node
        $this->reverse_list_right_of_node($nextNode); 
        //reverse nextNode
        $nextNode->next=$node; 
    }

    public function reverse_list_recursively() {
       $head=$this->head;
       //reverse everything to the right of head
       $this->reverse_list_right_of_node($head);
       //make head point to null (if list is non-empty)
        if($head!=NULL){
            $head->next=NULL;
        }
    }
```

The first method is a helper method that recursively reverses a part of the list to the right of a given `$node`. If `$node->next` is is `NULL`, then `$node` ought to become the head node. Otherwise, you can recursively reverse everything to the right of `$node`, and then reverse the connection between `$node` and `$nextNode`.

Then I use this helper method to implement the `reverse_list_recursively()` method. In this method you simply reverse everything to the right of the `head` node and then make the `head` node point to `NULL` since it is to become the last node.

Now there is a way to do this without the helper method

```
    public function reverse_list_recursively($node=NULL) {
        //treat $node==NULL as a special case
        $topLevel=false;
        if(!$node){
            $node=$this->head;
            $topLevel=true;
        }
        if($node->next==NULL){ 
            $this->head = $node;
            return;
        }
        $nextNode = $node->next;
        //special case: set original head node to point to NULL
        if($topLevel){
            $node->next=NULL;
        }
        $this->reverse_list_recursively($nextNode); 
        $nextNode->next=$node; 
    }
```

I have given and implementation below. You give the `$node` a default value and test for the default value, and handle things specially in that case. I think this looks uglier and is harder to understand than the other implementation I gave.